# Llamado de listas dentro de una función

Tags: python, lista

¿Cómo puedo invocar a diferentes listas dentro de una misma función. Es decir, que en la consola escriba el nombre de mi función y entre paréntesis el nombre de una lista en específica mostrando lo que he indicado, y así, no ver todo mi programa, sino la lista que indique.

Por ejemplo:

```
alista = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
blista = ["casa", "auto", "calle", "avenida"]

def listas(mis_listas):

    print(alista)     
    print(alista[0])
    print(alista[-1])
    alista.append("i")
    print(alista)
    
    print(blista)
    print(blista[0])
    print(blista[-1])
```

listas(alista)

Mostrando lo que he indicado solo para alista

listas(blista)

Mostrando lo que he indicado solo para blista

Comment: Solo utiliza la variable `mis_listas`, por ejemplo haz `print(mis_listas);print(mis_listas[0])`

Comment: Mi idea es recorrer las listas usando bucles. Y al invocar una lista, en la consola baste con escribir el nombre de mi función y el nombre de mi lista.

Comment: por eso, eso es lo que te digo. Mejor voy a escribir una respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Al definir una función puedes definir si es que esta función recibirá argumentos. Estos argumentos son como un "alias" de la variable que le estas pasando a la función. Por ejemplo:

```py
def saludo_persona(persona):
    print(f"Buenos días/tardes/noches {persona}")

saludo_persona("Christian")
saludo_persona("Daniel")
```

Esto imprimirá el saludo con el nombre de la persona que hallas puesto en los argumentos. Esto es debido a que dentro de la función la variable `persona` toma el valor que pases, sin importar cual sea, puedes pasar una lista, número o valor booleano e igual funcionará y esto es lo que tú quieres.

```py
alista = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
blista = ["casa", "auto", "calle", "avenida"]

def listas(mi_lista):
    print(f"""{mi_lista}
    {mi_lista[0]}
    {mi_lista[-1]}""")

listas(alista)
listas(blista)
```

Y esto imprimirá:

```py
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
a
e
["casa", "auto", "calle", "avenida"]
casa
avenida
```

Comment: Oh, vale! Con el primer ejemplo que pusiste me quedó más claro! Muchas gracias por la ayuda!.